# Can't get custom configuration points working for my VS Code extension

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

So I've been spending a lot of time trying to get a couple specific settings working for my language extension in VS Code, and while the documentation and the few articles online seem to make it sound as simple as adding a "configuration" point in my package.json and a "getConfiguration()" call in the extension.ts file, it seems that there is more needed to get them working. This is my first extension I've made so I'm a bit unfamiliar with some of these things.

I am working on this project for work, so I will paste some of my code below with certain edits. The main issue I am getting right now is that it recognizes that I have added the configuration points to the package json, but I get this error when trying to debug the extension:

[Cannot register '<configuration_name>'. This property is already registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvuty.png)

I have read as much as I can online about this and it seems that maybe the issue is that VS Code is seeing these settings as already defined and therefore is confused because it may be expecting custom configurations. I'm not sure. I feel though the issue must lie in my extension.ts file since when I look at the configuration example on the VS Code Examples repository on Github, they are doing quite a lot more than just the simple "getConfiguration()" function I am using. But I really have no idea what I would do. I am not very familiar with typescript as of yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated on this. Anyone have any insight as to why it would be doing this?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "ex-lang",
"displayName": "Example",
"description": "Example language support",
"version": "0.0.1",
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.64.2"
},
"categories": [
    "Programming Languages",
    "Snippets"
],
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "ex",
            "aliases": [
                "EX",
                "ex",
                "Example"
            ],
            "extensions": [
                ".ex"
            ],
            "configuration": "./language-configuration.json",
            "icon": {
                "light": "./icons/icon.png",
                "dark": "./icons/icon.png"
            }
        }
    ],
    "grammars": [
        {
            "language": "ex",
            "scopeName": "source.ex",
            "path": "./syntaxes/ex.tmLanguage.json"
        }
    ],
    "snippets": [
        {
            "language": "ex",
            "path": "./snippets.json"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": [
        {
            "id": "ex-config",
            "title": "Example Custom Settings",
            "properties": {
                "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
                    "textMateRules": [
                        {
                            "scope": [
                                "comment.block.documentation.ex"
                            ],
                            "settings": {
                                "foreground": "#efc752"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
                "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#2b85d5",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#559ddd",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#80b6e6",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#aaceee",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#d5e7f7",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#c6cad4",
                    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#db6165"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"dependencies": {
    "vsce": "^2.9.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.40.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.19.0",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
}
```

}

I have tried messing a bit with Activation Events, but I was getting more issues with it as I suppose I don't understand them as well as I might like. I have also fiddled with different scopes for the configuration points and such but to no avail. And lastly, I did have a "main" contribution point, but I was having very strange pathing issues when I had it (it kept saying the file was not found), so I removed it. Not sure if any of these things are also contributing to my problem or not.

Here is my extension.ts file for reference:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('ex-config');

}
```

Comment: you can only contribute the definition of new settings in `package.json`, what you are doing is filling in the settings with values, this has to be done in `settings.json`. in `package.json` you specify the scheme of a setting, what is the type and possible properties if it is an object, possible enums,.....

Comment: your settings will be useless for the theme I use and that other people use, some have dark theme, some have light theme, some have high contrast theme

Comment: @rioV8 Ah ok that would make sense. I looked into editing the settings.json instead before but I guess I was approaching it wrong. So I would just add the scheme of the settings in the package.json then and notify the user in the README about those options? I'm assuming they will probably show up in the preferences menu after the scheme is created. And about the settings conflicting with themes, that's a good point, this is more just a basic example of what I am trying to do. Ideally once I figure out how to actually edit it, I'll try to find a way to color things differently based on theme.

Comment: why do you want to change settings that have theme specific values with the extension?

Comment: you can't set the scheme for these settings in your extension because they are already defined by the core VSC, just mention these settings in your readme, it should already be defined by the theme developer so these colors have a value that fits the theme

Comment: Well again ideally I would try to find a way to add a few different versions based on theme, but I'm building this for some of the engineers at work, working on an in-house language. In other editors, they are used to the embedded documentation being highlighted different than regular comments. But for all the themes I tried, it highlights  them the same way as other comments. And then the regular bracket pair colorization is just god awfully bright and sticks out like a sore thumb imo.

Comment: I see, shoot alright. Yeah I suppose it would be better to have the user define it anyway, to better match their individual theme. Well thank you for the quick reply! I appreciate it

Comment: add some custom TextMate Scopes to differentiate the different type of comments, the users can specify the colors for these names scoped by theme, or you can prepare a complex setting that each user can use, you can put it in the `.vscode/settings.json` file of the workspace